# How to write notations of equations in LaTeX. (Text and Mathematical operator together)

Tags: math-mode, symbols, subscripts, syntax

I want write the following  sentences in LaTeX.

> `n_e` and `n_i` are the density of electrons and ions; `m_\alpha` and `Z_\alpha` are the mass and charge number of species `\alpha`;
>   `v_e` and `v_i` are the average (drift) velocity of electron and ion; `T_e` and T_i are the electron and ion temperatures;
>   Temperature range `(1.5<z<=10)`.

Please advice me

Answer (score 2):

You almost do what you like to achieve. See, if this works for you (I just ad `$` before and after your variables, which put them in math environment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$n_e$ and $n_i$ are the density of electrons and ions; $m_{\alpha}$ and $Z_{\alpha}$ are the mass and charge number of species $\alpha$; $v_e$ and $v_i$ are the average (drift) velocity of electron and ion; $T_e$ and $T_i$ are the electron and ion temperatures; Temperature range $(1.5<z\le10)$.
\end{document}
```

Above example gives:

[image]

Comment: `\leq` rather than `<=` perhaps.

Comment: Yes, ylou have right. I overlooked this.